# Limiting lines in kivy TextInput?

Tags: python, kivy

Is there a way I can limit the lines a user can enter in a TextInput in kivy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can control whether the TextInput supports multiple lines with the *multiline* option. You can set `multiline=True` and then check the contents of the widget after an input event for a line count, optionally discarding a new line when necessary. You'll have to do the housekeeping yourself, but it's doable.

I don't see an easier way at this time to config the widget to not exceed a certain max number of lines. You'll have to limit the line count via your code.

Comment: You can always grab all the text in the widget and count new line characters. Or split the text into lines and count the number of lines...

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to eliminate the ability to have multi-lines?
If so use,
`multiline=False` in the python file, or:
`multiline: False` in the kv file.

Comment: no i want multiline but the user can enter only 4 lines and not more